# Minimax Theorems V.S. Fixed Point Theorems.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Is there any relationship between the **minimax theorems**
$$
\mbox{Regularly hypothesis on } f:U\times V\to\mathbb{R} \implies \min_{u}\max_{v}f(u,v)=\max_{v}\min_{u}f(u,v)  
 $$
and **fixed point theorems**
$$
\mbox{Regularly hypothesis on } F:X\to X \implies F(x)=x, \mbox{ for some } x\in X ?
 $$
More precisely, there is some kind **theorem minimax** implies some **fixed point theorem**? Or **fixed point theorem** implies some type **minimax theorem**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One direction is given historically in game theory. Nash's result on the existence of Nash equilibria, [essentially a fixed point theorem](http://theoryclass.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/brouwer-implies-nash-implies-brouwer/), implies the minimax theorem of von Neumann. Here is the coarse structure of the argument. We want to rewrite $$f:U\times V\to\mathbb{R} \implies \min_{u}\max_{v}f(u,v)=\max_{v}\min_{u}f(u,v)$$
as the solution to a fixed point problem. For this we have to generalize the idea of a fixed point to *correspondences*, or *set-valued mappings*. If $\phi:S\to 2^S$ maps points in $S$ to subsets of $S$, we say that $s$ is a *fixed point* of $\phi$ if $s\in\phi(s)$. One can often prove fixed point theorems for correspondences from fixed point theorems for functions by using selection or approximation theorems.

So we define a correspondence $F:U\times V\to 2^{U\times V}$ by letting $$F(u,v)=\{u'\in U:u'\text{ minimizes } f(\cdot,v)\}\times\{v'\in V:v'\text{ maximizes } f(u,\cdot)\}.$$
Now the fixed points of $F$ are exactly the solutions to the minimax problem.

Comment: @Greinecker, good answer. Some reference? Book or an article? Thanks.

Comment: @Elias For the finite dimensional case, there is the nice book *Fixed Point Theorems with Applications to Economics and Game Theory* by Kim Border.

Comment: @Grinecker, thanks! I went back to take interest in this topic again. I'm interesting in writing a paper review. Something very simple. But first I want to check if what I had in mind was not already done before.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Can you explain more why "fixed points of F are exactly the solutions to the minimax problem."? Thanks.

Comment: @Hermi Which direction is unclear?